# Rename column name - Excel

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

Is it possible to rename a column header using `xlsxwriter` module? I think that it should be possible but I can't figure out how. I've checked `set_column` method but with no success.

```
set_column(self, firstcol, lastcol, width=None, cell_format=None,
                   options={}):
```

Maybe in options dictionary?
Do you have any advice for me?

Comment: Is it possible to rename a header in Excel?  If so, how?

Comment: @jmcnamara According to, f.e. this http://smallbusiness.chron.com/give-name-columns-excel-73447.html it can be done. But I have not Excel so I can't try it. I want to do that programatically.

Comment: If you read that carefully, or try it, you will see that it doesn't actually rename the column header. It creates a defined name for the column. That is also possible in XlsxWriter but it may not be what you are looking for. I'd suggest trying it in Excel first to see if it meets your requirements. Renaming column headers in Excel isn't possible, as far as I know.